# how to DrawPath Trajectory Like below game Reference in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, draw, game-physics

**I want to create ball aim preview path with touch input and I try it and created just single direction but i want to create with arc in 3 type.**

**target and origin position are fix but change arc curve path change depend on control**

1. If User Swipe Right Side so Draw Path Origin to target with Arc and arc curve with right side x = 10
2. If User Swipe left Side so Draw Path Origin to target with Arc and arc curve with left side x = -10
3. If User in center so Draw Path Origin to target with Arc and arc curve with X = 0

   ```
   void Update()
   {
       if (Application.isMobilePlatform)
       {
           // If pressed with one finger
           if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
           {                            
               pressX = Input.touches[0].position.x;
               pressY = Input.touches[0].position.y;
           }
           else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
           {
               pressX = 0;
               pressY = 0;
           }


           if (pressX != 0)
           {
               float currentX = Input.touches[0].position.x;

               if (currentX < pressX)
                   XValue = (currentX - pressX) / 100;
               else if (currentX > pressX)
                   XValue = (currentX - pressX) / 100; 

               if (target.transform.position.y < 45.0f)
               {

                   TargetPosition = target.transform.position;
                   print("YValue : " + YValue);
                   TargetPosition.x += XValue;
                   TargetPosition.y += YValue;
                   target.transform.position = TargetPosition;
               }
               else
               {
                   TargetPosition = target.transform.position;
                   print("YValue : " + YValue);
                   TargetPosition.x += XValue;
                   TargetPosition.y += YValue;
                   if (target.transform.position.y > 45.0f)
                       TargetPosition.y = 45;
                   target.transform.position = TargetPosition;
               }

               DrawPath();
           }
           if (pressY != 0)
           {
               float currentY = Input.mousePosition.y;

               if (currentY < pressY)
                   YValue = (currentY - pressY) / 100;
               else if (currentY > pressY)
                   YValue = (currentY - pressY) / 100;

               if (target.transform.position.y < 45.0f)
               {

                   TargetPosition = target.transform.position;
                   print("YValue : " + YValue);
                   TargetPosition.x += XValue;
                   TargetPosition.y += YValue;
                   target.transform.position = TargetPosition;
               }
               else
               {
                   TargetPosition = target.transform.position;
                   print("YValue : " + YValue);
                   TargetPosition.x += XValue;
                   TargetPosition.y += YValue;
                   if (target.transform.position.y > 45.0f)
                       TargetPosition.y = 45;
                   target.transform.position = TargetPosition;
               }

               DrawPath();
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
           {
               pressX = Input.mousePosition.x;
               pressY = Input.mousePosition.y;
           }
           else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
               pressX = 0;


           if (pressX != 0)
           {
               float currentX = Input.mousePosition.x;
               float currentY = Input.mousePosition.y;

               if (currentX < pressX)
                   XValue = (currentX - pressX) / 100;
               else if (currentX > pressX)
                   XValue = (currentX - pressX) / 100;

               if (currentY < pressY)
                   YValue = (currentY - pressY) / 100;
               else if (currentY > pressY)
                   YValue = (currentY - pressY) / 100;


               if (target.transform.position.y < 45.0f )
               {

                   TargetPosition = target.transform.position;
                   print("YValue : " + YValue);
                   TargetPosition.x += XValue;
                   TargetPosition.y += YValue;
                   target.transform.position = TargetPosition;
                   //target.transform.position = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y + YValue, target.transform.position.z);
               }
               else
               {
                   TargetPosition = target.transform.position;
                   print("YValue : " + YValue);
                   TargetPosition.x += XValue;
                   TargetPosition.y += YValue;
                   if (target.transform.position.y > 45.0f)
                       TargetPosition.y = 45;
                   target.transform.position = TargetPosition;
               }

               DrawPath();
           }
           else
           {

           }
       }

       if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
       {
           print("Mouse Click Call");
           //Rigidbody obj = Instantiate(ball, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

           //obj.velocity = Vo;
           ball.position = transform.position;
           Physics.gravity = Vector3.up * gravity;
           ball.useGravity = true;
           ball.velocity = CalculateLaunchData().initialVelocity;
       }     
   }
   ```

i created like :

[image]

And I want Like : [Reference Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWyW4p1QUXE)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can calculate the trajectory with a [quadratic Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)
where p0 and p2 are your start and ending point and p1 is half way between p0 and p2 with your added x value